# Remove file:// prefix c#

Tags: c#

I have the follow:

```
string file = string.Concat(
                 System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
                    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase
                 ), 
              "bla.xml");
```

Now file is:

```
file:\C:\test\Debugbla.xml
```

How can i remove the "file:\" prefix?

Thanks

Comment: `.Replace("file:\", "")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class is the way to manipulate Uri. While `string.Replace` is an option it is better to use tools explicitly designed for particular case which also take care of handling escaping rules where necessary.

```
string file = string.Concat(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
     System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "bla.xml");

file = new Uri(file).AbsolutePath;
```

**UPDATE:**

More robust implementation eliminating `string.Concat` to handle other cases including fragments in the codebase url.

```
var codebase = new Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);

var file = new Uri(codebase, "bla.xml").AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: [LocalPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) probably  is better fit , but indeed `Uri` class is proper way of dealing with Uris.

Comment: Yes localpath turns the forward slashes into back slashes. I also think it might fix other things in the file name either now or in future so definitely a better strategic option

Comment: I have a path with a # and Uri plays it as the hash section of an Uri (Named as Fragment in Uri class)

Comment: @Noman_1 i'm unclear what's the end goal is, but since it's a url you need to URL encode it like this `file:\C:\temp\c%23\something.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Assembly.Location` property instead, which returns a normal filepath.

Also, use `Path.Join()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
file = file.Replace(@"file:\", "");
```

You can replace it with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the file:\ part of the path like so.

```
string file = string.Concat(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase), "bla.xml");
file = file.Replace(@"file:\","");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the path you can use GetExecuting Assembly and convert it into an Uri:

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
```

Or using Location:

```
string fullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(DaoTests)).Location;
```

If you just need the directory and the entry point, the following will work:

```
var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;

var folderPath = @"C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Music\";


foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.*"))
{
    var newFile = file.Replace("[SPOTIFY-DOWNLOADER.COM]", "");
    File.Move(file, newFile);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 6 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.